How to set environment variables and copy Files to workers in GCP Dataflow
I am writing a dataflow job which read data from SQL Server using a Kerberos KeyTab Authentication.
I have 3 config files sal_jass.conf , krb5.conf and keytab files and  set below Environment variable while running the java code
JAVA_TOOLING_OPTIONS = "-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf  -Dsun.security.auth.login.config=/etc/sql_jass.conf"

Using these config files and the environment variable am now able to connect to the database by executing simple Java code from GKE POD manually.
Now am trying to do the same using dataflow job
Problem here I have is Dataflow does not have access to config files which are inside POD and POD level Environment variables are not accessible to Dataflow workers.
I have 2 questions

How to make this files available to dataflow workers.
How to Set/Pass the Environment variables in workers.

AS of now its not using the krb5 file nor the sql_jass file to authenticate to DB so getting below error.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated Authentication Failed. ClientConnectionId:6f436f49-b0bf-441e-bab3-e6af86ac8361 due to javax.security.auth.login.LoginException (Cannot get any of properties: [password, PASSWORD] from con properties not available to garner authentication information from the user)


You cannot pass the env vars for workers. You should use PipelineOptions: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptions.html to define some GCS file paths, which contain the files you need. On the other hand, it is better to use jdbc IO: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/
